# Excel error 1004 “Unable to get RandBetween property of WorksheetFunction class”

Tags: excel, vba

The following code worked perfectly fine as written last week. I have been working in Excel 2013 and 2010 recently so this may have caused the issue.

I run the code today and it properly executes the code. Meaning the values in the specified sheets and columns change each time I run the macro. However I get the error in the title of this post when I do run it.

I have read other posts that say to add Application in front of WorksheetFunction and this does not work either. I get the same message.

```
Sub rndScore()
Dim Lrow As Integer 
Dim Srow As Integer 
Lrow = Sheets("Programs").Cells(Rows.count, 19).End(xlUp).Row 

For Srow = 9 To Lrow 
    Sheets("Programs").Cells(Srow, 26).Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(10, Sheets("Programs").Cells(Srow, 19) * 100000000000#) / 1000000000 
Next Srow 
End Sub
```

Comment: `100000000000#` I'm not overly familiar with RandBetween. What does the `#` sign do?

Comment: if you eliminate `sheets("programs").cells(Srow,19)` and set it to 20... does it work?  if So the problem is likely in the `srow` value or the existence of `"programs"` worksheet. or in the value of (srow,19)

Comment: @xQbert I was thinking along the same lines. Are you sure that `Sheets("Programs").Cells(Srow, 19) * 100000000000#` is greater than 10?

Comment: That specific error message occurs when the value for sheets("Programs")cells.(srow,19) contains no value.  So within your loop you're encountering a non numeric value.  If I had to guess the .exnd(xlup) is hitting some blank lines.  If you delete the rows with spaces after the last row with data it may start to work again.  Step though and look at the value for LROW to determine if it exceeds the last row with data.